# From where can I get the Mini-Profiler-Resource folder needed by MiniProfiler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to use miniProfiler in my MVC 4 project. But after installing both, miniProfiler and miniProfiler.Mvc4 and trying to run my project, MiniProfiler is not loading. In the console log show that it is trying to get a file from a folder named "mini-profiler-resource" but I dont have nothing named that in my project.

Am I missing to install something?

Answer (score 3):

It is not an actual folder - rather it is a route that should be set up in MVC for you to access the resources.

Try adding the following to your web.config (per [miniprofiler.com](http://miniprofiler.com))

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <handlers>
    <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```